# Plotting the logarithm of a function

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib, logarithm

I have a function which I am able to plot.
Now I would like to plot the logarithm of this function. Python says that log10() is not defined for functions (and I understand that). 
So the question is: how can I plot the logarithm of a function like f(x,a)=a*(x**2)?

Comment: Is your problem calculating the logarithm base 10 or plotting the values? If the latter, how is that different from plotting anything else? Also, your `f(x,a)` is a function of two values. Do you want to plot for changes `x`s and a constant `a`?

Comment: x should be my variable and a a parameter that I can put in when it comes to plotting the function. the problem is that I can't define a correct function, e.g. g(x,a)= log10(f(x,a)) because I can't put a function into the log.

Comment: I mean what I basically want to tell the program is: given f(x,a) (that I already plotted) use the log10() on every point of that function and plot it

Comment: You have to compute the log of the values and plot them.  If you have, say, `y = f(x, a)` and you have already done `plot(x, y)`, you can do `plot(x, np.log10(y))`.  You'll probably want a new figure, or at least a new set of axes, for that plot.  OR, if you are trying to do a "log plot" (i.e. a plot with a logarithmic scale), see the matplotlib plotting function [`semilogy`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is misleading to say that matplotlib can plot functions. Matplotlib can only plot values.

So if your function is

```
f = lambda x,a : a * x**2
```

you'd first need to create an array of values for `x` and define `a`

```
a=3.1
x = np.linspace(-6,6)
```

You can then plot the array `y = f(x,a)` via

```
ax.plot(x,y)
```

If you now want to plot the logarithm of f, what you need to really do is plot the logarithm of your array `y`. So you'd create a new array

```
y2 = np.log10(y)
```

and plot it

```
ax.plot(x,y2)
```

In some cases, instead of showing the logarithm of a function on a linear scale, it may be better to show the function itself on a logarithmic scale. This can be done by setting the axes in matplotlib to logarithmic and plot the initial array `y` on that logarithmic scale.

```
ax.set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
ax.plot(x,y)
```

So here is a showcase example of all three cases:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#define the function
f = lambda x,a : a * x**2

#set values
a=3.1
x = np.linspace(-6,6)

#calculate the values of the function at the given points
y =  f(x,a)
y2 = np.log10(y)
# y and y2 are now arrays which we can plot

#plot the resulting arrays
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10,3))

ax[0].set_title("plot y = f(x,a)")
ax[0].plot(x,y) # .. "plot f"

ax[1].set_title("plot np.log10(y)")
ax[1].plot(x,y2) # .. "plot logarithm of f"

ax[2].set_title("plot y on log scale")
ax[2].set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
ax[2].plot(x,y) # .. "plot f on logarithmic scale"

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your difficulty is calculating the logarithm base 10, use

```
def g(x, a):
    return math.log(f(x, a)) / math.log(10)
```

or just

```
def log10(x):
    return math.log(x) / math.log(10)
```

That gives an error for non-positive values, which is what you want. It uses the standard identity

> log of x base b = log(x) / log(b)

It does not even matter which base that `log()` function uses: you'll get the same answer for any base.